# An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("A "__toString()"

Tags: php, symfony

I've got this error while continuing with 
tutorial.symblog.co.uk[Part 4]`-`The Comments Model: Adding comments, Doctrine Repositories and Migrations]

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type "Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog" passed to the choice field. To read a custom getter instead, set the option "property" to the desired property path.")
>   in BloggerBlogBundle:Blog:show.html.twig at line 23.

does any one got a clue on this?

```
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php 
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\BlogRepository‌​") 
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog") 
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks() 
 */ 
class Blog { 
    //.......... 
    public function __toString() { 
        return $this->getTitle(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that is giving the error?

Comment: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html<?php
// src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php

namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\BlogRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Blog
{
   //..........
    public function __toString()
    {
       return $this->getTitle();
    }
}

Comment: This I found it from here http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html and I was following "The view" section thnx..

Comment: @bartek gave you the answer below. That should solve your issue(s).

Answer (score 3):

Just add `__toString()` method in your `Blog` entity

```
class Blog {

    //...

    function __toString() {
        return $this->getTitle(); // or any other field
    }
}
```